# Is it possible to upload a file to a website, only by modifying the HTML and CSS code?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to upload a file to a website, so I can download it later from another location. Is there a way to do this solely by modifying the HTML/CSS code of the website?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it displays a fundamental lack of understanding of the languages at hand.

Comment: In HostGator for example, you get "Code edit" option when you right-click.

Comment: @nosille How does that produce HTML or CSS which lets you upload a file for later download?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Neither HTML nor CSS are programming languages (meaning they allow you to interact with the server and its files) and, if it were allowed, anyone could upload files to a site's server.

Comment: I believe that's exaclty what the OP wants to do (on another one's website)! lol

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You just need to modify the HTML/CSS code of the website.

Comment: I would like to see your markup that would do that because it is my belief that your claim is impossible.

Comment: Hey Rob, sorry that wasn't very clear. Just right-click and choose "View page source"

Comment: I still don't see how doing that would allow him to upload a file to a server which he can then download at a later date using only HTML and CSS.I am asking you to produce such a markup.

Answer (score 0):

html and css are markup language or language that render/format the website depending on the designers wishes, that being said, it is possible for anyone to modify the two for any website as one wishes hence for security purposes i dont think its possible to use them only to upload a a file to a server, u will need a backend scripting language to do that such as PHP or ASP among others